# How to update nested properties in state using spread operator and bind nested array of objects into input fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

stackoverflow is my only last HOPE, please HELP ME.

- So i am creating a simple system, where i am using reactjs and springboot.

So this is my Entity for Student. as you can see it has DbRef into myCourse entity (All API'S ARE WORKING FINE TESTED IT USING POSTMAN)

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Document(collection = "Student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private @Getter @Setter String id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String middleInitial;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String studentId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String gender;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String temporaryAddress;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String permanentAddress;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String contactInformation;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String academicLevel;

    @DBRef
    @ElementCollection
    private @Getter @Setter List<Course> myCourse;

}
```

This is myCourse entity.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Document(collection = "Course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    private @Getter @Setter String id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String courseCode;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String courseTitle;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String instructor;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String schedule;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String semester;
}
```

- fast forward i want to create a form in my front end to accept a data like what i written in entity.

So i created a state with a bunch of properties of student and nested a myCourse with its own properties as well.

[image]

And this is how i destructure them

```
const {
        firstName,
        middleInitial,
        lastName,
        studentId,
        dateOfBirth,
        gender,
        temporaryAddress,
        permanentAddress,
        contactInformation,
        academicLevel,
        myCourse: [
            {
                courseCode,
                courseTitle,
                description,
                instructor,
                schedule,
                semester
            }
        ]
    } = student;
```

and this is my onChange function

```
const updateStudentForm = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setData(() => ({ ...student, [name]: value.toUpperCase() }));
      };
```

then i created a form so i tried bind the values and name of my state into it, while the student properties were working fine, the myCourse properties do not, when i am typing into fields of student properties the values changed.

```
 <Col>
                            <FloatingLabel
                                controlId="floatingInput"
                                label="Student ID"
                                className="mb-3"
                            >
                                <Form.Control type={"text"} placeholder="Student ID" required
                                    {...register("studentId")}
                                    value={studentId}
                                    onChange={(e) => updateStudentForm(e)}
                                    autoSave="off"
                                    autoComplete="off" />
                            </FloatingLabel>
                        </Col>
```

while into myCourse the values do not change.

```
 <Col>
                            <FloatingLabel
                                controlId="floatingInput"
                                label="Course Code"
                                className="mb-3"
                            >
                                <Form.Control type={"text"} required placeholder="Course Code"
                                    {...register("courseCode")}
                                    value={courseCode}
                                    onChange={(e) => updateStudentForm(e)}
                                    autoSave="off"
                                    autoComplete="off" />
                            </FloatingLabel>
                        </Col>
```

PLEASE HELP.

I want to create a form where i can collect data from student and their courses.

This is my onSubmit form and when i test my API in postman, it works, all my API's for CRUD are performing well.

```
const response = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/clerk/student/add-new', student)
            if (result.status === 200) {
                setData(result.data);
                navigate("/admin-home")
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            setTimeout(StudentDuplicate(), 300)
        }
    }
```

its just that i cant bind the values of myCourse into my input fields

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `myCourse` is an array of objects and you're trying to bind their properties directly like this `value={courseCode}`

You can change all your `onChange={(e) => updateStudentForm(e)}` to:

```js
onChange={(e) => setData(() => ({ ...student, student.property: e.target.value.toUpperCase() }))}
```

Replace `student.property` to the correct property. That way you can do the following to `myCourse` for example:

```js
<Form.Control type={"text"} required placeholder="Course Code"
   {...register("courseCode")}
   value={myCourse[0].courseCode}
   onChange={(e) => setData(() => ({ ...student, student.myCourse[0].courseCode: e.target.value.toUpperCase() }))}
   autoSave="off"
   autoComplete="off"
/>
```